Problems running Powershell code within Batch file
In this question It's said that using the following code ought to create a clean execution of powershell code:
PowerShell ^
   $BIOS= Get-WmiObject -computername \"BAHRIATSG2-PC\" -Namespace;  ^
   root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface;  ^
   $BIOS.SetBIOSSetting('Setup Password','<utf-16/>TheBIOSPassword','<utf-16/>')
pause

It's mentioned that any " needs to be preceded by a \ and each command needs to be followed by ; ^ except the last one..
Anyway, here's the code I'm trying to get working. It's to switch a Firewall rule off and on, then to change the icon of the shortcut that runs the batch file containing the code:
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="OBRule" | findstr "^Enabled:.*Yes$"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="OBRule" new enable=no
    ren S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundON.lnk OutboundOFF.lnk

echo OUTBOUND RULE DISABLED!

@echo off

PowerShell ^ 
    $shortcutPath = \"S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk\"; ^
    $iconPath = \"C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\OBOFF.ico\"; ^
    $WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; ^
    $shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath); ^
    $shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath; ^
    $shortcut.Save();

) else (
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="OBRule" new enable=yes
    ren S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk OutboundON.lnk

echo OUTBOUND RULE ENABLED!

@echo off

PowerShell ^ 
    $shortcutPath = \"S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundON.lnk\"; ^
    $iconPath = \"C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\OBON.ico\"; ^
    $WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; ^
    $shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath); ^
    $shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath; ^
    $shortcut.Save();

)

pause

The codes work flawlessly in their respective native environments,but when I run the script like this (with the supposedly correct powershell formatting) in a .bat file it flashes a cmd prompt for a fraction of a second but does nothing at all.
I have also tried this format:
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -command "& {

$shortcutPath = "S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk"; ^
$iconPath = "C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\AEOFF.ico";

$WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;

$shortcut= $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath);

$shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath;

$shortcut.Save();
}"

But this returns a "missing }" issue that doesn't go away unless I put them all in one unbroken line string within the brackets, and I think (too tired to try it again) that makes a weird infinite loop where a million things go wrong and it starts opening new windows until I can catch the most recent before the next one opens.
What am I missing here?
TIA!

Run it from a command prompt instead of by double-clicking the file, so you can see the output that is produced.

You could try it like this: 1. %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command^, 2. €"$shortcutPath = \"S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk\";"^, 3. €"$iconPath = \"C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\OBOFF.ico\";"^, 4. €"$WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;"^, 5. €"$shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath);"^, 6. €"$shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath;"^, 7. €"$shortcut.Save()". Due to comment formatting problems, please replace all € characters above with space characters, before testing.

The linked duplicate summarizes the - obscure - escaping rules. In short: Since your powershell.exe CLI call is made from inside the body of an if statement, ) characters must be ^-escaped too.

< and > also needs to be escaped if you run like that, because single quotes ' are just normal characters in cmd, which makes your command receives <utf-16/ as the input redirection and >TheBIOSPassword',' as the output stream, and then redirect stdin/stdout again => syntax error. Always use " in cmd

It looks like you're missing some indentation, line continuation characters (^) and double quotes.  I'm not 100% certain about every line (except the first line) needing to be indented, but if you do indent the lines, the last "}" also needs to be indented otherwise you'll get an error about the string not being terminated.
Try this as a .bat script:
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -command "& {"^
 "$shortcutPath = 'S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk';"^
 "$iconPath = 'C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\AEOFF.ico';"^
 "$WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;"^
 "$shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath);"^
 "$shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath;"^
 "$shortcut.Save()"^
 "}"


As per my example in the comments, but without the need to make modifications:
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command^
 "$shortcutPath = \"S:\Libraries\Desktop\OutboundOFF.lnk\";"^
 "$iconPath = \"C:\Windows\System32\Customization\Icons\OBOFF.ico\";"^
 "$WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;"^
 "$shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath);"^
 "$shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath;"^
 "$shortcut.Save()"

You can also play around with the number of spaces either side of the first doublequote on line two onwards. The only requirement is that there must be at least one before it.
